# How to check if a View reach the end of ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an app that adds views programmatically to a linear layout.

The problem is if I add too many views it will go off the screen.

I would like to know how to check if a certain child has hit the end of the same view group so I could add it into another layout (a linear layout below the first one) before it "flows" and go off the screen. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: What you're asking might become more clear if you include the code that is producing undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinvent the wheel yourself, I suggest that you check out the **FlexboxLayout** project by Google: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

A `FlexboxLayout` will automatically give you the behavior you're describing, plus the potential for much more.

Comment: how far have you gone? gotten an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a good number of ways you could implement this in android other than going through this hustle. What ever you are trying to do at the moment may fall under one of the following cases.

1. Creating views programmatically most likely means you have a dynamic data set probably from an external source.
2. Your dataset is limited or static but just more than the average screen can display.

if any of the above apple then you are better off using a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) or [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) (Recommended). That way your data is full displayed as a scroll-able list and you don't have to worry about some items or views not showing or going of the screen. This can range from simple string list to complex nested views.
This will be very efficient as it will automatically handle optimization and usage of memory as well as performance.

Comment: I am trying to do like this Duolingo test. So recyclerview won't help here. http://prntscr.com/iko5ja

Comment: ok well looking at your picture looks like using layout weight and weight sum atttributes of a horizontal LinearLayout should work.